# Change selection of current li element

Tags: jquery, if-statement, html-lists

I have a list:

```js
var $curr = $('#lol').children().first()
var $last = $('#lol').children().last()
$curr.css("z-index", "1");

$("#next").click(function() {
  if ($curr == $last) {
    $curr = $curr.first();
    $("li").css("z-index", "");
    $curr.css("z-index", "1");
  } else {
    $curr = $curr.next();
    $("li").css("z-index", "");
    $curr.css("z-index", "1");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <button id="prev" type="button">prev</button>
  <button id="next" type="button">next</button>
  <ul id="lol">
    <li id="a">1</li>
    <li id="b">2</li>
    <li id="c">3</li>
    <li id="d">4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

After clicking the next button i'd like to change style of next li item, but if it's a last li element of ul list it should change a first li element.

I dont't know how to chceck if $curr is the last one element of the list and go to first one. Please help :)

Comment: don't mind but @adeneo's answer was really better than the other one. Since this question is for beginner, his answer will help ppl in writing a cleaner and efficient code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two jQuery objects are never the same, but you can use `is()`

```
if ( $curr.is( $last ) ) {
```

or compare the native DOM nodes

```
if ( $curr.get(0) == $last.get(0) ) {
```

It's generally easier to use classes to apply style changes

```js
var elems = $('#lol li');

$( "#next" ).click(function() {
    var next = elems.filter('.active').next();
    if ( next.length === 0 ) next = elems.first();
    
    elems.not( next.addClass('active') ).removeClass('active');
});

$( "#prev" ).click(function() {
    var prev = elems.filter('.active').prev();
    if ( prev.length === 0 ) prev = elems.last();
    
    elems.not( prev.addClass('active') ).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
#lol li {
    z-index : 0;
    color : black;
}

#lol li.active {
    z-index : 1;
    color : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
<button id="prev" type="button">prev</button>
<button id="next" type="button">next</button>
<ul id="lol">
    <li id="a" class="active">1</li>
    <li id="b">2</li>
    <li id="c">3</li>
    <li id="d">4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $curr = $('#lol').children().first();
var $list = $('#lol').children();

$curr.css( "z-index", "1" );

$( "#next" ).click(function() {
    $( "li" ).css( "z-index", "" );

    if (($curr = $curr.next()).length === 0) {
        $curr = $list.first();
    }

    $curr.css( "z-index", "1" );
});
```

Basically, if calling `next()` assigns an empty jquery object to `$curr` it sets it to the first child again.